# Hexadecimal regular expression string matching does not work (python)

Tags: python, regex, hex

I have a hexadecimal string as follows (for example)

```
'0x100x200x3f0x2d0x300x330xd0xa'
```

and I want to extract all the stuff between the header

```
'0x100x200x3f0x2d'
```

and the tail

```
'0xd0xa'
```

In the example given above the expression I want to extract using regex is

```
'0x300x33'
```

in general, the string searched for can consist of an arbitrary number of two-digit hexadecimal numbers. I have tried the following

```
a = re.compile('0x100x200x3f0x2d([0x[0-9a-f]{2,2}]+)0xd0xa')
```

which does not match my example string! I just require `0x` followed by exactly two hex digits `0-9a-f` (always smallercase, inner rectangular bracket), to be in the string at least once (outer rect. bracket `+`). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So one should never have two [] nested?

A `[` nested within a character group will make the outer character group include the `[` character. The character `]` will close the first character group, making the second `]` a static character.

So your regular expression `([0x[0-9a-f]{2,2}]+)` would be interpreted like this:

```
[0x[0-9a-f]{2,2}]+
^^^^^^^^^^^
character group with the characters: 0, x, [, 0-9, a-f
           ^^^^^
           two of those
                ^^
                followed by at least one ]
```

So it would for example match the following weird things:

```
00]
00]]]]]]]]]
[[]
xx]
ff]
```

Instead, you don’t want a character group, but a normal matching group (note that `{2,2}` shortenes to just `{2}`):

```
((0x[0-9a-f]{2})+)
```

This will of course generate a second group in the match results (because you have two catching groups). You can change that by making the inner group a non-capturing one by prefixing its content with `?:`, i.e. `(?:...)` will group but not yield the results in the match.

```
((?:0x[0-9a-f]{2})+)
```

Comment: perfect. and thanks for the clear explanations of the various terms.

Comment: One question, though. Without using the term `?:` the `findall` methods returns `[('0x300x33', '0x33')]`. What happened to `0x30`, shouldn't that be found as well?

Comment: In a result set, each group is only included once. That means for constructions like `(x)+` the group will only contain the last result. That’s why you will usually nest those in another group which you will actually look at, i.e. `((x)+)`. So `0x30` was found, but the second group’s content was then overwritten by the other match, `0x33`.

Comment: How to 'keep' all of them instead? I.e. all matches for the inner group?

Comment: It’s not possible to do that. You could run another `findall` on the outer group though with `0x[0-9af]{2}` as the regexp. Or, as you know that it will always be groups of 4 characters, just split it into 4 character groups.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to repeat the character class `[]` instead of a group. So you are basically asking for any amount of `0x[0-9a-f]{2,2}` characters (so xxxx would also match).

This might work better:

```
a = re.compile('0x100x200x3f0x2d((0x[0-9a-f]{2})+)0xd0xa')
```

Comment: Ok I think I see the problem. So one should never have two `[]` nested? I now have two results, `[('0x300x33', '0x33')]`. I want the first in this list only. Is there a way to tell the regex to return only the longest matching string?

Comment: @Alex: The `[]` syntax cannot be nested. It means: "match any character inside here", so everything you put there is not processed as a regex. To obtain the match with maximum length just do `max(('0x300x33', '0x33'), key=len)`, but it depends on which method of the regex object you are calling(I believe you are using `findall` or `finditer`, right?)

Comment: When I use `findall` it scans the string from left to right, returning the matches in the order found. With that I should be fine to just refer to `a.findall(...)[0][0]`. But I do not quite understand the reason for the double-index...

Comment: @Alex `findall` returns a list of all matches it can find within the string. So the first `[0]` returns the first match. Each match now is an array of all matched groups within the match, so the second `[0]` will return the first group. If you are only interested in the first result, you can also just use `a.search(...).group(1)`.